# How to recalculate MKDirections when a user deviates from a route in swift

Tags: ios, swift, navigation

I'm programming a Simple navigation app and have a MapView with a MKDirections calculation displayed as a polyline in a overlay.

I'm really struggling to find any help online to allow the route to be recalculated automatically when the used deviates form the navigation route (polyline).

Does anyone know if there is a way of doing this? I guess you could calculate the distance from the route (polyline) and if that deviates by a certain amount trigger a recalculation but that seems really complex for what should be quite straight forward?

I'm using swift and only really have experience with swift.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: hi @Ultronn did you came up with a solution for this?